# Comparative efficiancy with inserting variables to simply adding text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, performance, optimization

Say I take the phrase "Please insert your answer here" and wish to repeat it many times within a program would it be *significantly* more efficient to print "Please insert your answer here" or to create a variable with that text to do the same function?

```
#First option
answer= input("Please insert your answer here ")

#second option
prepared_question= "Please insert your answer here "
answer= input(prepared_question)
```

Assuming this would be repeated many times, would there be a *significantly* more efficient option? Naturally, from a writer's Perspective, it is much nicer to simply re-use a variable and I question whether it takes more time.

Comment: The former will take slightly longer, the latter will occupy memory even when it doesn't need to.  Neither will ever be enough to matter. The latter is better because it makes it easier to change all of your messages as a group.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is (slightly) more efficient because it doesn't require two extra steps of `STORE_NAME` and `LOAD_NAME` during the interpretation.

```
In [3]: dis.dis("answer= input('Please insert your answer here')")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (input)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Please insert your answer here')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (answer)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: dis.dis("prepared_question= 'Please insert your answer here';answer= input(prepared_question)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Please insert your answer here')
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (prepared_question)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (input)
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (prepared_question)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 STORE_NAME               2 (answer)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

But from the functionality perspective, if the `input`'s message is supposed to change in future runs it's better to use a variable and probably a function.